# PL/SQL - Checking procedure argument slows its execution

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I execute the following procedure:

```
DECLARE

 PROCEDURE my_proc(arg1    IN NUMBER,
                   arg2    IN NUMBER)
 IS
      ltimestamp_start       timestamp;
      ltimestamp_stop        timestamp;
      linterval_diff         interval day to second;
 BEGIN    
    ltimestamp_start := systimestamp;

    UPDATE transfers t1
    SET t1.trn_valid = 'Y'
    WHERE EXISTS( 
        SELECT 1 
        FROM transfers t2
        JOIN tasks u1 ON trn_tsk_id = u1.tsk_id
        WHERE t1.trn_id = t2.trn_id
            AND t2.trn_pom_id = arg1
            AND u1.tsk_type <> 'TT'
            AND (
                (arg2 IS NULL AND t2.trn_ord IN ('W', 'K') AND t2.trn_type <> 'P' AND t2.trn_mng IN ('0', '1')) OR
                (arg2 IS NOT NULL AND t2.trn_ord IN ('W', 'K') AND t2.trn_type <> 'P' AND arg2 = t2.trn_id)
            )
    );

    ltimestamp_stop := systimestamp;
    linterval_diff := ltimestamp_stop - ltimestamp_start;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM linterval_diff));
 END;

BEGIN
  my_proc(200, 300);
END;
```

On average, it takes 0,085939s.

However, if I comment:

```
--(arg2 IS NULL AND t2.trn_ord IN ('W', 'K') AND t2.trn_type <> 'P' AND t2.trn_mng IN ('0', '1')) OR
```

the execution takes only 0,000275s.

In this case arg2 is equal to 300 but checking the condition "arg2 IS NULL" slows the procedure dramatically.

Any ideas why I get so strange results?

Comment: Did you repeat your benchmark several times? Execution times can differ depending on what data is already in memory.

Comment: Yes. I did. I get the similar scale of results for different data..

Comment: Please post the structure of the involved tables, including indexes, and the explain plans of the statements, with and without the commented lline

Comment: Uncommenting that line, you ask Oracle to check more table columns, and this needs more computation; the problem is due to this (what indexes do you have?) more than the evaluation of the procedure argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you comment out the `(arg2 IS NULL...` you are leaving only the mandatory condition that `t2.trn_id = arg2`, giving Oracle's optimizer a very clear access path (assuming `t2.trn_id` is more selective than `t2.trn_pom_id`).

Oracle's optimizer has a lot of tricks to transform `OR` queries into multiple parts that each access data differently and perform well.  It's possible that Oracle's tricks are failing it in this case.

You can try to help the CBO by splitting out the logic for it.  I believe your query is equivalent to the following, which Oracle's CBO might have a better time with:

```
UPDATE transfers t1
SET t1.trn_valid = 'Y'
WHERE EXISTS( 
    SELECT 1 
    FROM transfers t2
    JOIN tasks u1 ON trn_tsk_id = u1.tsk_id
    WHERE t1.trn_id = t2.trn_id
        AND t2.trn_pom_id = arg1
        AND u1.tsk_type <> 'TT'
        AND t2.trn_ord IN ('W', 'K')
        AND t2.trn_type <> 'P'
        AND t2.trn_mng IN ('0', '1')
        AND arg2 IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1 
    FROM transfers t2
    JOIN tasks u1 ON trn_tsk_id = u1.tsk_id
    WHERE t1.trn_id = t2.trn_id
        AND t2.trn_pom_id = arg1
        AND u1.tsk_type <> 'TT'
        AND t2.trn_ord IN ('W', 'K')
        AND t2.trn_type <> 'P'
        AND arg2 = t2.trn_id
        AND arg2 IS NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Also consider testing whether arg2 is null in PL/SQL and switching between two UPDATE statements.